# Hebrew in w3layout template

Tags: html, css, templates, hebrew

I'm pretty new to web design and would be grateful to get some help here.
I found this[template](http://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/drug-expo-medical-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/) and hoped to use it, but I need it to show Hebrew. I've tried to modify the CSS

> @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css);
>
> body{   font-family: "Alef Hebrew" }

and to add a link to the [Alef] font in the html index file. Nevertheless it still shows Hebrew as jiberish.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually linking the font in the `<head>`. Can you show us that code?

Comment: I put this just below the head

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "still shows Hebrew as jiberish" is weird.  Your browser should display Hebrew text in its default font if nothing else is compatible.

Anyway,

1. Declare HTML5 UTF-8.

   ```
   <head>
       ...
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       ...
   </head>
   ```
2. Make sure you are using a modern & updated browser
3. Make sure the template is downloaded and is on your computer
4. Open `css/style.css`
5. Just after the top comment (`*/`), paste:

   ```
   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css);
   ```
6. Add your `font-family` in the ***existing*** `body` selector:

   ```
   html, body{
       font-family: 'Alef Hebrew', 'Lato', sans-serif;
       ....
   }
   ```

Comment: I did like you said, but unfortunately this is what I get
https://www.dropbox.com/s/32gudb817s8r7vb/Screenshot%202015-01-21%2021.32.50.png?dl=0

Comment: I've tried it on most updated Firefox , Chrome and IE. The characters are a bit different, but still not Hebrew.

Comment: Can you see Hebrew [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA)? Yes=make sure your file is in UTF8 and that it is declared in `head`. No=it is a problem with your system.

Comment: תודה רבה נדב.
I added <meta charset="utf-8"> and the problem is solved.

Comment: בכיף! This is the exact declaration you need. Happy it is solved.